# Trying to add an Item to my cart, this error shows: ASP.NET Core MVC ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating an online store and I want the user to be able to add items to the cart by clicking a button. However, when I click the button, I get the titled error. However, even though the error pops up. The item still shows up in the cart.

Can somebody please help me with this? Thank you

Inventory view:

```
@* @model IEnumerable<LootXApp.Models.Inventory> *@

@using WebApp.Controllers
@using WebApp.Data
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Taghelpers

@model dynamic

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Shop with us !</h1>
@{
   IEnumerable<Inventory> inventory = (ViewData["IndexInventory"] as IEnumerable<Inventory>)!;
   IEnumerable<Checkout> checkout = (ViewData["IndexCheckout"] as IEnumerable<Checkout>)!;
}

@{
    var myList = inventory.ToList();
    var clicked = false;
}

@for (var i = 0; i < myList.Count; i = i + 2) {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="itemPic" src="../../Images/@Html.Raw(myList[i].InventoryPic)" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="sec1">
            <h2 asp-for="InventoryName">@Html.Raw(myList[i].InventoryName)</h2>
            <p>@Html.Raw(myList[i].InventoryDescription)</p>
            <p>$@Html.Raw(myList[i].InventoryPrice)</p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCartItem", "Inventory", new{Id=myList[i].InventoryId},FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
            }
            
        </div>

        @if (i + 1 != myList.Count)
        {
            <div class="col">
                <img class="itemPic" src="../../Images/@Html.Raw(myList[i+1].InventoryPic)" alt="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col" id="sec1">
                <h2>@Html.Raw(myList[i+1].InventoryName)</h2>
                <p>@Html.Raw(myList[i+1].InventoryDescription)</p>
                <p>$@Html.Raw(myList[i+1].InventoryPrice)</p>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCartItem", "Inventory", new{Id=myList[i+1].InventoryId},FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Inventory controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebApp.Data;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class InventoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _contextCheck;
        
        public InventoryController(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationDbContext contextCheck)
        {
            _context = context;
            _contextCheck = contextCheck;
        }

        public List<Inventory> GetInventory()
        {
            List<Inventory> inventory = new List<Inventory>();
            var connectionString = "Data Source=identifier.db";
            
            var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connectionString).Options;
            
            using var inv = new ApplicationDbContext(contextOptions);
            inventory = inv.Inventory.ToList();
            return inventory;
        }

        public List<Checkout> GetCheckout()
        {
            List<Checkout> checkout = new List<Checkout>();
            var connectionString = "Data Source=identifier.db";
            
            var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connectionString).Options;
            using var check = new ApplicationDbContext(contextOptions);
            checkout = check.Checkout.ToList();
            
            return checkout;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["IndexInventory"] = GetInventory();
            ViewData["IndexCheckout"] = GetCheckout();
            return View();
        }
       
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexInv()
        {
              return _context.Inventory != null ? 
                          View(await _context.Inventory.ToListAsync()) :
                          Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Inventory'  is null.");
        }

        // GET: Inventory/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Inventory == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var inventory = await _context.Inventory
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.InventoryId == id);

            if (inventory == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(inventory);
        }

        // GET: Inventory/ShowItem
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowItem()
        {
            return _context.Inventory != null ?
                        View() :
                        Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Inventory'  is null.");
        }

        // PoST: Jokes/ShowSearchResults
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSearchResults(String SearchPhrase)
        {
            return _context.Inventory != null ?
                        View("ShowItem", await _context.Inventory.Where(i=>i.InventoryName.ToLower().Contains(SearchPhrase.ToLower())).ToListAsync()) :
                        Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Inventory'  is null.");
        }

        // GET: Inventory/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Inventory/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("InventoryId,InventoryName,InventoryDescription,InventoryPic,InventoryPrice")] Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(inventory);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(inventory);
        }
        
        // GET: Inventory/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Inventory == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var inventory = await _context.Inventory.FindAsync(id);

            if (inventory == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(inventory);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCartItem(int Id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Id < 0 || _context.Inventory == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                var cart = _contextCheck.Checkout;

                var item = await _context.Inventory.FindAsync(Id);

                var newItem = new Checkout();
                string? name = item?.InventoryName;
                string? pic = item?.InventoryPic;
                decimal price = item.InventoryPrice;

                if (item != null)
                {
                    newItem = new Checkout(name, pic, price);
                }
                
                _contextCheck.Add(newItem);
                await _contextCheck.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("InventoryId,InventoryName,InventoryDescription,InventoryPic,InventoryPrice")] Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (id != inventory.InventoryId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(inventory);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!InventoryExists(inventory.InventoryId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(inventory);
        }

        // GET: Inventory/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Inventory == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var inventory = await _context.Inventory
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.InventoryId == id);

            if (inventory == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(inventory);
        }

        // POST: Inventory/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Inventory == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Inventory'  is null.");
            }

            var inventory = await _context.Inventory.FindAsync(id);

            if (inventory != null)
            {
                _context.Inventory.Remove(inventory);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool InventoryExists(int id)
        {
          return (_context.Inventory?.Any(e => e.InventoryId == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a condition to handle the null but that still didn't work so I removed it. I also checked my connection strings since I read that could possibly be an issue, but everything on that end seems to be in order.

Comment: Which line of code is producing the error?  When you debug, what are the observed runtime values of the variables used in that line of code?

Comment: This is the line producing the error:
'var myList = inventory.ToList();'

The inventory variable has a null value for some reason when that line of code is executed, which keeps throwing the exception.

Comment: *"The inventory variable has a null value for some reason"* - Well, where does that variable **get** its value?  It looks like it comes from `ViewData`.  Was `ViewData` populated with the value you expect?  Was it populated with anything at all?  You're showing **a lot** of code here, so it's difficult to tell.  When you debug, what specific request is being made to the server which returns this view?  Which specific controller action is returning this view when the error occurs?

Comment: When you first hit the index page, it's hitting that "GetInventory()" method and setting ViewData.  When you post to the CreateCartItem() method, you're not doing that... so no "ViewData" is set when you return the view.  (Though it has nothing to do with your question, you should consider switching over to binding to class objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0 )

Comment: I apologize for being vague, still very new to this. 

The ViewData seems to be populated with the products from our Inventory database upon inspecting it with the debugger. The Index action in the Inventory Controller is responsible for populating ViewData["IndexInventory"] with inventory data.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments on the question:

> This is the line producing the error: 'var myList = inventory.ToList();' The inventory variable has a null value for some reason when that line of code is executed, which keeps throwing the exception.

The error happens on this line in the view:

```
var myList = inventory.ToList();
```

So if `inventory` is `null`, where does it get its value?  Here:

```
IEnumerable<Inventory> inventory = (ViewData["IndexInventory"] as IEnumerable<Inventory>)!;
```

So if `ViewData["IndexInventory"]` is `null`, where does it get its value?  Here:

```
ViewData["IndexInventory"] = GetInventory();
```

But wait... this only happens in this action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
```

But when you submit the form, you invoke this action method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCartItem(int Id)
```

Which returns this same view:

```
return View("Index");
```

But *doesn't* put anything in `ViewData` before returning that view.  So `ViewData["IndexInventory"]` will be `null`.

You *could* populate `ViewData` just as you did in your other action method:

```
ViewData["IndexInventory"] = GetInventory();
ViewData["IndexCheckout"] = GetCheckout();
```

*But*, taking a step back, it's probably better not to return a view at all in this case.  Instead, redirect back to the `Index` view:

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```

In the long run you'll generally find that it's easier to reason about and less prone to error if you follow this general pattern:

- GET - Fetch data and return view
- POST/PUT/DELETE - Update data and redirect back to GET

That way you don't have to duplicate all of the code for fetching data in the operations which modify data, and you cleanly separate fetching data from modifying data.  It'll also make easier use of framework standards because you won't have to worry about using the same view on very different URLs.  (Since the browser doesn't know/care about any of the server-side code and just fetches resources relative to whatever URL it's on.)